# ExecutionEngine not recognizing parameter

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

I'm using Neo4j 1.8.RC1, and trying to generate the clustering coefficient for nodes in my graph.

I've got the following code, which as far as I can tell is working on a Linux system, but does not work on my Windows machine:

```
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();

String query;
String typeString;

if (type == <some type>) {
    typeString = "TYPE1";
}
else {
    typeString = "TYPE2";
}

params.put("myid", userid);
query = "start a=node(*) match (a)-[:"+ typeString +"]-(b) WITH a, count(distinct b) as n "
        + "match (a)-[:" + typeString + "]-()-[r:"+ typeString+"]-()-[:"+typeString+"]-(a) where a.thisId! = {myid} return n, count(distinct r) as relcount";

ExecutionEngine engine = new ExecutionEngine(graphDb);
ExecutionResult result = engine.execute(query, params);
```

When I try to access result, I get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException:    org.neo4j.cypher.ParameterNotFoundException: Expected a parameter named myid
```

I've stepped through and verified that it's there.  What's going on?

Comment: "I'm using Neo4j 1.8.RC1" -- Do you mean **1.9** RC1?

Comment: Why are you using 1.8RC1? 1.8 has been stable for a long time now. They're on to version 1.8.2. You may very well be experiencing a bug that was fixed between 1.8.RC1 and 1.8.2.

Comment: The short answer is that upgrading is non-trivial.  If there's a definite issue that needs to be addressed, fine, but upgrading a system that otherwise works in the target environment is not an option.

Comment: I recommend setting up a development environment and testing your code against 1.8.2 to see if the issue is resolved. If the issue goes away then you have choice but to upgrade. Upgrading is non-trivial, yes, but it's also not impossible. Upgrading neo4j is a binary drop-in replacement. You have to do testing, but you need to be prepared to accept software updates for bug fixes. That is the nature of software.

Comment: I agree that it is the nature of software.   As I said, I am prepared to update for necessary bug fixes, but since the code was working fine in the target environment, I was gunshy about updating.  That said, moving to 1.8.2 appears to have fixed the problem, so I will be updating in the target environment as well.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As the comments above have noted, this problem was resolved by updating from 1.8.RC1 to 1.8.2. Though I don't have a bug report to point to, this was clearly a bug in Neo4j that was resolved somewhere between those versions.